# Assign each 'cell' in a numpy grid with a value, possibly using a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

So I am creating a grid of ones and zeros using numpy:

```
grid = np.zeros((N, N))
grid = rnd.randint(2, size = (N, N))
```

I want to be able to give each cell a value called 'age', something such as

```
grid[i,j]age = 1
```

Then the age will increase for each timestep, and I can work out each cells age so I can kill it if it gets too old, something like this:

```
if grid[i,j]age > 10:
   grid[i, j] = 0
```

Looking online it seems that python does not let you change the variable names and I should be using a dictionary, but I am not sure how to implement this, any help would be appreciated, and I can give more info if needed.

Comment: Why don't you use 2 arrays of the same shape -- one for the values themselves and one for the ages? No need for some special syntax here.

Comment: Fairly new to programming so to check I understand: use 2 grids, such as grid and then age_grid = grid.copy() and then acces the ages from there?